Angular DI: Helper function that uses inject()
I have a utils file that has some helper functions exported as constants in an Angular project. I'd like some of these functions to inject a service:
export const myFunc = () => {
  const s1 = inject(MyService);
  s1.function('asdasd/adasd');
};

This works if this function is executed in an injection context, e.g., in a component constructor. But when it's run outside of it, it will not (BTW Angular is not showing any error in the console in this case but it should, I think it's a bug). What would be the best way of doing this not running into anti-patterns or bad practices?
The way I'm doing it now is not intuitive and I think the consumer should not know if the function has to be run in an injection context or not.

The framework itself has several similar functions, like toObservable, toSignal, effect, takeUntilDestroyed etc.
You should probably do 2 things:

call assertInInjectionContext(), to throw properly if you're not in an injection context
add an Injector as optional parameter, this way to you call runInInjection or call injector.get if you're not currently in an injection context.

An example here

yep, I used the assertInInjectionContext inside the function to make it more robust since I though that the injection error was not being thrown because of that. I was quite surprised to see that it was still not being thrown (it smells like bugs). Then I saw this in the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-context#using-di-outside-of-a-context. So inject should throw the error without the need of assertInInjectionContext

I like the second option, explicit and clean. Thanks
